# Haskell invalid type signature

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

Quick question, what is wrong with this?

```
(get) :: [a] -> Int -> a   -- <- line 21
(x:xs) get 0 = x
(x:xs) get (n+1) = xs get n
```

ghci gives this error when I try to load the file that contains that code.

```
Prelude> :load ch6.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ch6.hs, interpreted )

ch6.hs:21:0: Invalid type signature
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I'm trying to make get an infix operator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't have parentheses around `get`, to start with. The syntax for the whole definition looks a bit off, though. I'm guessing you wanted something like this:

```
get :: [a] -> Int -> a
get (x:xs) 0 = x
get (x:xs) (n+1) = xs `get` n
```

Note the backticks around `get` in order to use it infix, which is necessary here because the rules for an alphanumeric identifier are different from operators: Operators are made of symbols, are are infix by default, and to write them without arguments or use them prefix, you put them in parentheses. Alphanumeric identifiers are prefix by default, and surrounding them with backticks lets you use them infix.

You can use the backticks on the left-hand side as well, if you want, but that looks a bit odd to my eye:

```
(x:xs) `get` 0 = x
(x:xs) `get` (n+1) = xs `get` n
```

Incidentally, the pattern syntax `n+1` is deprecated, so you probably shouldn't use that. Instead, do this:

```
(x:xs) `get` n = xs `get` (n - 1)
```

Comment: I'm working off [prelude](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html). Check the source for &&.

Comment: @Kevin: That's how it works for operators, i.e. identifiers made of symbols. The syntax is different for alphanumeric identifiers.

Comment: Not only deprecated: it doesn't work in stock GHC any more (and is not in Haskell 2010).

Comment: (n+1) works for me in whatever ghci comes in the Ubuntu package :)

Comment: @ehird: "It doesn't work anymore" is simply the point at which an aggressive deprecation metastasizes. :]

Comment: @Kevin: Oh, huh, seems it's still enabled by default in the latest GHC (7.2.2). I must have misremembered. They're definitely not in the latest standard, though.

Comment: @ehird No, as of ghc-7.0.*, `NPlusKPatterns` is disabled by default. The last to not give a parse error without the extension is 6.12.3. Where did you get a 7.* that accepts them by default?

Comment: @DanielFischer: I was going by [the docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#n-k-patterns).

Comment: @ehird: The docs apparently haven't been updated. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @ehird Already updated in HEAD, seems it was forgotten to merge the change into the 7.2 branch.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you put it in parenthesis doesn't make it an infix function.  Infix functions can only be made via symbols or backticks.  See the [Haskell report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4) for specifics.